# Как за ХОR'ить (зашифровать) строку?

Tags: c++, строки

```
std::string URL = "https://yandex.ru" + site() + ".ini";
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну так `for(int i = 0; i < URL.length(); ++i) URL[i] ^= ....`

Или `for(auto& с : URL) с ^= ....`

Примерно так...

Comment: как понять ^= ....

Comment: Так же, как `+=` для сложения или `-=` для вычитания.

Comment: все равно не понял, компилятор требует выражения!

Comment: сорри если тупой вопрос я просто больше веб программист

Comment: `a = a ^ b` и `a ^= b` - эквивалентные записи! Если есть бинарный оператор `@`, то `a @= b` - сокращенная запись для `a = a @ b`. В принципе, бывают и исключения, но для простой арифметики и логики - это так.

Comment: хе хе вспомнил)